# Dynamic dependency between Multi-Picklist and Text field

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-record-page, dynamic-forms

I'm Configuring Dynamic dependency between Multi-Picklist and a Text Field.

**Desired Result:** When I Select `Other` from Multi Picklist then the `Proof Details` Should become required Otherwise it should be Optional or Hidden (Component Visibility)

[image]

**Scenario:** I'm Trying to achieve this by dynamic forms on the lightning record page. But the Multi-Picklist field `Proofs Attached` is not listed to control the Text Field `Proof Details`
[image]

How to Achieve the Desired Result

And Is it right to try to achieve this in lightning or should it be done in apex? Note: I'm a Beginner

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this with Apex or in the UI. Use a Validation Rule instead to check if the Proof Details text field is empty or not. You may even check for the length of the input if you don't want users to bypass it with a single character input.

Something like this:

```
AND(
  INCLUDES(AttachedProofsMPick__c, "Other"),
  OR(
    ISBLANK(ProofDetails__c),
    LEN(ProofDetails__c) < 10
  )
)
```

This reads as "if the value of 'other' is selected and the proof of details value is blank or if it's length is less than 10 characters", and should be the criteria for your Validation Rule on this object.

Comment: Thanks for the response , Renato. Actually, I need to achieve this result using Lightning; that's my task. So are there any possibilities with UI(Lightning)?

Comment: Validation rules work regardless of which UI/experience you are using. :)